# Putting a folder into version control using Subversive under Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, merge, conflict

I've got a branched project under SVN control which I am programming using Eclipse, and which I checked out using Subversive (the SVN Eclipse plugin).

I wanted to be able to make changes to a relatively stable version of the code while simultaneously making some fairly major changes to a branch.  Today I made some changes to the core, tried to merge them into the branch and, not very surprisingly, found a small number of conflicts.  However, there was only one real source conflict—the changes have very little overlap—so I thought things were going OK.

Unfortunately, all the (fairly major) changes I've been making in the branched code are now, apparently, not under version control.  Clicking "Add to version control" only gives me a list of java files, but the packages (i.e. the folders) are not under version control, and Subversion doesn't seem to allow for this.

Almost all the SVN posts I've seen on here assume that SVN is being used through a shell; I am not using it through a shell.  I am using Tortoise and Eclipse under Windows.

I did try one idea, which was to create one of the "unversioned" folders in a secondary copy of the repo using Tortoise; this led to a different conflict when I tried to do an update, where it said the unversioned folder clashed with the versioned one.

Last time I merged something, ten years ago, it was not this painful, though admittedly we did it through a command line.  Can anyone help, please?

SOME OF THE ERRORS

```
svn: 'C:\Users\PCW\workspace\NewsRack Dev Branch\src\com\nrl\newsrack\billing' is not under version control

svn: 'C:\Users\PCW\workspace\NewsRack Dev Branch\src\com\nrl\newsrack\billing' is not a working copy
```

Comment: You should add some information about: Subversion plugin you are using, structure of your SVN repo, how you have checked out your project (TortoiseSVN or Eclipse), ...

Comment: Using an Eclipse plug-in like Subclipse makes managing Subversion much easier through Eclipse.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Subversive but called it Subversion by accident because I was in the throes of stabbing my computer with a garden fork.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit vague, so I will try to give some hints on what to look:

1. Find (in your windows explorer) your workspace directory of Eclipse and your Eclipse project in it. Is it under version control? TortoiseSVN should show one of its icons to denote that.
2. If it is not under version control, you have to add it, But be careful that only the resources you want to live in your SVN repo should be added. So you have to add your root folder of your project, but have to keep out all the binaries.
3. If is is under version control, find the first folder that is not and add that to Subversion.
4. You may then commit is as a whole.

It would be much easier if you would use an Eclipse plugin like Subversive or Subclipe. Both have the option to add a whole project to Subversion (in Subversive, the command is named `Share project`), and your plugin will then take care which resources to add and which not.

When you have added more information to your question, I will add more to my answer :-)

Comment: I am already using Subversive under Eclipse; the folders in my workspace directory have .svn subfolders, but I didn't want to mess around with these as I remember having problems with them before.  So: 1 Tortoise doesn't know about these folders 2 I've been trying to but Subversion doesn't seem to let me add FOLDERS to source control, only files.

Comment: I should also say I actually checked the project out from an SVN repo using subversive, but I've since 1 added some folders to one branch and 2 tried to merge the trunk into that branch.  I've also realized I failed to check IN the new folders before the merge, which is almost certainly part of the problem; I am slowly reintegrating the new source into the tree manually using my Tortoise repo checkout, but it's a bit of a mess.  Help would, therefore, still be appreciated.